# The folder is not created in the internal memory on android 10

Tags: java, android

My code with all necessary permissions does not create a folder on android 10 (Writes: "Failed to create folder"). What could be causing this? Help me please - don't really understand the error in my code.

Activity (if you need the rest of the code, I can throw it off):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (hasPermissions()){
                 makeFolder();
            }
            else {
                 method for requesting permission to work with files from the user();
            }
        });
    }

private void makeFolder(){
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(),"Folder");

    if (!file.exists()){
        Boolean ff = file.mkdir();
        if (ff){
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Folder created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed to create folder", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Folder already exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Try  file.mkdir without the boolean ff

Comment: Eh, no results...

Comment: What do you get? A crash or nothing happens? Are permissions granted?

Comment: All permissions are given. The application does not crash, but the folder is not created either

Comment: If you have not added then add, requestLegacyExternalStorage=true in application tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Hi, What API are you targetting?

Comment: Mrudul, I am very grateful to you. Your line has exhausted my question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's make it simple. This is the method call to create the folder:

```
makeFolder ( getFolderPath() );
```

The method to get the folder path:

```
public String getFolderPath()
    {
        String path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/New Folder").getPath();
        return path;
    }
```

Now the main method that creates the folder:

```
private void makeFolder(String folderPath)
    {
        File file = new File(folderPath);
        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdir();
    Log.i("Folder path: " , " " + folderPath );
        } else {
Log.e("Folder not created" , "Already exists!")
    }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no answer fixed my problem. By the way, the code is working because it worked perfectly on android 5.1.1

Comment: Couldn't the problem be due to some 10 individual android resolutions?

Comment: Then I really don't understand what the problem is.

Comment: I have actually checked the repository several times!

Comment: Prince Ali, I tried to do one more action already in the finished folder and it did not work, so I tend to think that I have something with permissions, but I cannot figure out what exactly

Comment: How do you check for permissions? Try granting the permissions manually in the app's setting page

Comment: Can you imagine, I forgot to add this line requestLegacyExternalStorage = true. I added and this solved my problem. I sincerely thank everyone who wanted to help me with this problem! I consider the question to be settled.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `file.mkdir()`  with `file.mkdirs()` and this should solve your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, no answer fixed my problem. By the way, the code is working because it worked perfectly on android 5.1.1